# move files in svn repository head folder

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I need to move svn repository files from a top level folder to a subfolder, making the head folder of the subfolder the head of the repository. I'm not sure I' asking this correctly, but I need to move some files because of how my new ftp program stores backups.

Right now, the files are in `E:\xxxsite`.

The files need to be in `E:\_UltraStudioBackups\xxxsite\vh5vm1_wwwroot\xxxsite`.  This last folder is the one where the files will be.

But I need to be able to commit the files by Tortoise SVN right clicking on `E:\_UltraStudioBackups\xxxsite`.

I need to be able to see the SVN icons for all the subfolders when I click into the folder `E:\_UltraStudioBackups` so I don't have to drill down to each subfolder to commit.

I have Visual SVN Server, Visual SVN, and Tortoise.

Comment: move the working copy down to the subfolder and put a shortcut to it on the desktop?

Comment: Aren't you confusing a repository with a working copy?

Comment: Yes, it is the working copy files not the repository. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Duh, I finally figured this out. I did a checkout to the new top path, then moved the files to a subfolder in that path and committed.